# (Python) Multiple raised ValueErrors not displayed

Tags: python, error-handling, valueerror

I am using a script with multiple built-in raised ValueErrors that loops over certain files in a folder. It checks for conditions and should report an error message for every file looped if this occurs.

However, it only shows one ValueError message of one file, instead of all errors. It still executes the loop for the other files. So for example, I have file a and b which should both generate an error, but python only shows the error message of file a. I already checked it by deleting file a, and after running the script it does generate an error message for file b

Part of my code is

```
for f_name in os.listdir(path):
     if f_name.endswith('.xls'):
     ...
     if a < 0: 
          raise ValueError('error')
     else:
          xxx
```

Does someone know how to display all errors?

Comment: Note that ``raise`` will *immediately* tear down the stack until the next matching ``except:``. Your code raises only one error, because the loop is aborted by the first exception already.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should **try** and **except statement** to find which file raise Exception.
Use this.

```
try:
    if a < 0:
        raise ValueError('error')
    else:
        xxx
except ValueError:
    print(a) #this will print which file isn't satisfying the condition
```